# How can I make my animation goes from the bottom to top of my screen?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, surfaceview

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make this view grow with the time.

Here is the code for animation

```
SurfaceView surfaceViewTimer = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view_timer);
Animation surfaceGrowingAnimation = new TranslateAnimation
    (0, 0, Animation.ZORDER_TOP, 300);
surfaceGrowingAnimation.setDuration(5000);

surfaceViewTimer.startAnimation(surfaceGrowingAnimation);
```

I want to make this animation goes from the bottom to top of the screen. Currenty it is going from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ScaleAnimation`.

For instance, modify the layout so that the surface takes whole screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
     />
```

And then scale it on Y-axis from 0 to 1:

```
    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    surface.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, it is still going from bottom to top. What values have I to chage?

Comment: Oh I did not understand. See my new anwser then

Comment: Thank you. I think now it will work. But what would be the advantage of using ScaleAnimation instead TranslateAnimation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `TranslateAnimation` like this:

```
    final SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    surface.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TranslateAnimation translation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, surface.getHeight(), 0f);
            translation.setDuration(2000);
            surface.startAnimation(translation);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. But what would be the advantage of using TranslateAnimation instead ScaleAnimation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by combining Scaling and Translate Animation.Translate Animation will help in the change in position of the view while the Scale in animation will help in the Change of Size. And in your code use Accelerate_Decelerate interpolator. The interpolator will give the required effect. You can try out with the different types of available interpolators to achieve the effect.

Comment: Thank you. I will try using this. After I give a feedback.

Comment: Sure. But Do use the interpolators and experiment with each of the types of interpolators. It will give you the desired solution. Let me know if it gets the desired solution.